# Yahoo and pandas-datareader error: RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, pandas-datareader

I am unable to grab stock data from yahoo finance, even I have done updating pandas and pandas-data reader by commanding `pip install --upgrade pandas` and `pip install --upgrade pandas-datareader` on the terminal.

```
import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = web.DataReader('APPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-01', end='2022-08-17')
df
```

however I am keep receiving this error message:

```
RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/APPL/history?period1=1325390400&period2=1660795199&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I think your ticker or company id is misspelled. Could it be 'AAPL'?

**UPDATE**

In **google colab** you need to tune your headers. This works for me there

```
import requests
import pandas_datareader as web

session = requests.session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'

df = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-01', end='2022-08-17', session=session)
df
```

There is also a related issue here:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/923

Comment: Error message is still the same after correcting the spell.

Comment: Is your internet connection working fine? Try the url in your browser https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1325390400&period2=1660795199&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history

Comment: I can access to the website but it keeps showing the same error message.

Comment: I would update to latest versions of pandas and pandas_datareader and also close or restart your notebook (or whatever IDE are using).  Also import just the pandas_datareader library.

Comment: @YeJunKim see my update

Comment: This worked. Really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no stock called `APPL`. You probably wanted to write `AAPL`:

```
df = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-01', end='2022-08-17')
```

Comment: it is still the same after correcting..

Comment: It works on my side.  What are the versions of `pandas` and `numpy` in your IDE?

Comment: version for pandas is 1.3.5 and 0.9.0 for pandas-datareader

Comment: Both your `pandas` and `web` is not up-to-date . It's interesting since you upgraded them, where did you upgrade those two and where did you run the above code.  `web` should be of at least version `0.10` I believe

Comment: I am doing this on google colab. could that be the reason?

Comment: It could be that you do not have connection from there...

Answer (score 0):

```
 pip install --upgrade pandas-datareader
```

Once you install it you have to delete existing runtime so that what you install come into force.

Follow these steps:

```
click on Runtime
select Disconnect and delete runtime
```

it will reset your current runtime and then

```
click on Runtime
select Run all
```

Apart from that the ticker you mention is wrong

```
Incorrect ticker : APPL # you mention this ticker in your code
Correct ticker   : AAPL
```